# Using lambda expression to select array element where it matches in string

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to select an element in array, that matches something in a string.

For example:

```
string[] splitChar = new string[] { "+=", "-=" };
string content = "5+=2";
```

So i want to check if content, contains something from `splitChar`, and if it does then select the value so it can be assigned to a string variable.

Comment: What if it finds more than one element? Or isn´t this possible? `5+=2-=1`?

Comment: In my case it wouldn't be possible, thank you for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas and LINQ would be overkill for this. You can just do a simple `foreach`:

```
string match = "";
foreach (var str in splitChar)
{
    if (content.Contains(str)) 
    {
        match = str;
        break;
    }
}

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(match))
{
    // Do whatever with `match`
}
```

If you really wanted to use LINQ, though, `FirstOrDefault` would be your best bet:

```
string match = splitChar.FirstOrDefault(s => content.Contains(s));

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(match))
{
    // Do whatever with `match`
}
```

Comment: Thank you for both options, worked just as i needed.
Yeah i know that a foreach would of been better, but for some reason the person asking for this project, wants lambda to be in place.
Will mark as solved, as soon as i can

Comment: Why would it be overkill? I think the LINQ version expresses the intent much clearer than the foreach loop...

Comment: @Timitry I said it's overkill, not cleaner. It depends on what your priorities are. Personally, I don't like throwing around LINQ methods just because I can when a simple `for` or `foreach` loop will do the same job just as effectively. This is production code, not code golf. If intent needs to be expressed, add comments.

Comment: @Abion47 Alright, I got what you mean! Although I don't think that LINQ has anything to do with code golf. I do a lot of functional-style programming in C# and always favor LINQ to loops - in production code. But since this is a matter of taste, we don't need to discuss that :-)

Comment: @Abion47 `I don't like throwing around LINQ methods just because I can when a simple for or foreach loop will do the same job just as effectively.` In my opinion, LINQ is the easier way to implement simple iterations. It cuts down on nesting and unnecessarily long foreach statements for e.g. a simple filtering action, and it increases readability (once you understand the basics behind lambdas). LINQ really shines when you can process every item of a list separately and the outcome of processing one row does not influence another row's outcome.

Comment: @Flater LINQ doesn't eliminate nested loops. It merely hides them behind a method call; `FirstOrDefault` still has a loop internally. That being said, I do agree that LINQ is indispensable when a complicated series of loops, filters, and queries need to be performed on a collection. But when all you are doing is performing a single iteration over a list and finding the first element that satisfies a simple condition, then there's not really any need to break out the LINQ.

Comment: @Abion47: `LINQ doesn't eliminate nested loops. It merely hides them behind a method call` Therefore reducing nesting visually and improving code readability. I've never heard a discussion about nesting that wasn't about code readability. `iterating over a simple list and finding the first element that satisfies a simple condition` So you're telling me that this is unnecessarily contrived? `myList.FirstOrDefault(x => simple_condition(x))` ? Even if you used a foreach and if, you would still be writing the same condition, but you would need several statements to do what this does in one line.

Comment: @Flater The difference is not that much. If we were talking about 1 line versus 20, then I would agree with you. As it stands, it's such a small difference that I leave it to personal preference, and I'd rather write an extra line or two if it meant I can use my own code that is just as efficient if not slightly more so than a pre-built one and have the benefit of knowing _exactly_ what that code is doing. Besides, put the above logic in a method, and there's your one-liner.

Comment: @Abion47: I'm not telling you that you can't do it your way. But it seems counterintuitive to the strength of .Net, where the simplification of existing logic (that does not need to be altered anymore) and code reuse leads to significantly easier to maintain projects. E.g. I wouldn't suggest you write your own XML parser, because there are simply so many fringe cases (e.g. CDATA) you will forget to account for. There's little point to reinventing the wheel other than training purposes.

Comment: @Flater LINQ is a tool that trades control and understanding for convenience and conciseness. Granted, it is very good and flexible at what it does, but when people make a habit of using it for every little thing, then it's abuse. It trains people to use it to the point that they don't know what to do without it. Use LINQ where it turns convoluted code into much simpler and easier to understand, but I discourage people from using it (especially in a learning environment) in trivial applications like simple iteration.

Comment: @Abion47: So basically "Don't use a better tool for this, because you might keep using it because it's easier" I completely disagree. While I do agree that training should also include things like basic foreach skills (etc.); that does not mean new starters are required to keep doing things the oldschool way just for the sake of not forgetting how we used to do things. No one still codes like they did 10/20 years ago. When lists and ienumerables became a thing, there were people claming that "arrays still offer better control and it's not that hard to index-check". This is the same thing.

Comment: @Flater It's not a "better tool" if it does literally the exact same thing in the exact same way (and you can go look at the source for the `FirstOrDefault` method if you want to see that). The only difference is cosmetic, and even then is just 2-3 lines. I've already said multiple times that LINQ is preferable in many cases of greater complexity, and am merely expressing my preference over this specific instance where the benefits are trivial. There is virtually no practical benefit to using LINQ over a `foreach` in this _specific_ case.

Comment: @Flater This is like saying that you should always use an HTML parser even in cases where you will only be dealing with a single line of HTML and simply using Regex would suffice. In trivial situations, it's a valid opinion to say that the "intended" tool is overkill.

Comment: @Abion47: If you're parsing a HTML string that you created yourself, I can agree with that (closed data loops require less validation overall) If you need to be able to parse _any_ HTML string that your application is provided with, you better make sure you've covered all cases. Which would mean either reinventing the wheel or having to call a list of established HTML decoding/parsing methods. Or using a parser that is _specifically intended to do the job you want your application to do_.

Comment: @Flater I'm done arguing with you on this. You'd rather adhere yourself to using these tools in 100% of cases, whereas I think that in cases of trivial complexity the tool is unnecessary. We shall agree to disagree.

Comment: @Abion47: I was done, but the last thing I want to highlight: `You'd rather adhere yourself to using these tools in 100% of cases` That is downright false. From my initial comment: `LINQ really shines when you can process every item of a list separately and the outcome of processing one row does not influence another row's outcome.`

Comment: @Flater And from what I said _several times_, `It's not a "better tool" if it does literally the exact same thing in the exact same way.`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking with `FirstOrDefault` like the following?

```
string[] splitChar = new string[] { "+=", "-=" };
string content = "5+=2";        
var stringPresent = splitChar.FirstOrDefault(x=>content.Contains(x));
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringPresent))
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
else
Console.WriteLine(stringPresent);
```

Check this [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tSMuW4)

Comment: Should of mentioned that i'd like to assign the value it finds, to a string variable, not check if its present

Comment: @SimonIsaksen: Could you please take a look into the updates as well as the example and let me know is that what you are looking

Comment: Yeah, this does the work just aswell, thank you for your solution :)

Comment: @SimonIsaksen: Glad to hear that.. Happy coding